# Not able to build native package in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have downloaded latest `sencha gpl 2.1.1` and `sdk cmd 3.0.2`, So here i am able to generate sample app as in the sencha website. but i am not able to build native package. it is throwing error in command prompt like this `com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException:`

> The following error occured while executing this line:
>
> D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:109:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/User%202/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/
>   antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1

Can any body tell why it is giving error how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `compass` is [installed](http://compass-style.org/install/) before compiling.
You can skip it with adding `skip.sass=1` to your `sencha.cfg` files.